How to increase VLC RAM buffer for offline files using CLI?
I would like to do the same thing as in the answer to this question: I want to increase the File Caching option found in the preferences (Tools -> Preferences) with all the parameters (the All button selected in the bottom left corner of the screen), then by selecting Input / Codecs, under the Advanced section.
However, I use VLC on a Raspberry Pi to play music without any UI, and I only have a SSH access to this Raspberry Pi. Therefore, I’m looking for a CLI solution (editing a configuration file or using the cvlc command).
My vlcrc is empty and I don’t know the exact name of the parameter.
I use VLC version 3.0.21 Vetinari (revision 3.0.21-0-gdd8bfdbabe8) installed via apt. I have Raspbian 12 (bookworm).
Thanks in advance

How do I set the file-caching from the command line?
Use vlc --file-caching ....
Syntax:
--file-caching=<integer [0 .. 60000]>
     milliseconds of video to buffer in RAM when the video source is a file)

Source: VLC command-line help - VideoLAN Wiki
